# String returning null

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am facing issues getting the string values using e.ClickedItem.

Here's how my ListView looks like:

```
 <ListView
        x:Name="PoemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PoemListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Poems In Item"
        TabIndex="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Poems}"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="PoemView_PoemClick" 
        SelectionMode="None"
        SelectionChanged="PoemSelectionChanged"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0"
            ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <StackPanel   Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,27.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                            <!--<CheckBox x:Name="PoemCheckbox" Checked="ContentChecked" Unchecked="ContentUnchecked"/>-->
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="PoemId" Name="PoemId" Text="{Binding PoemId}" DataContext="{Binding}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="PoemTitleId" Text="{Binding PoemTitle}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=FontSlider, Mode=OneWay, Path=Value}" DataContext="{Binding}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="PoemMeanId" Text="{Binding PoemMean}"  DataContext="{Binding}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is the code behind the xaml page:

```
private void PoemView_PoemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {


     TextBlock PoemId = e.ClickedItem as TextBlock;


       this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Favorite), (e.ClickedItem as TextBlock));
```

On LoadState event of the Favorite page, I have added the below code:

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
     string poem = e.NavigationParameter as string;


     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(poem))
       {
           FavText.Text = "no favorite text";

        }

       else { FavText.Text = poem;

     }

    }
```

The problem is in the LoadState while the e.NavigationParameter is loaded with the strings passed to it, the string poem is not loading properly. Therefore, the FavText.Text is always returning the "no favorite text".

Anyone has a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting e.ClickedItem as TextBlock, I updated the code as below which worked perfectly fine:

```
var type = ((PoemItem)e.ClickedItem).PoemTitle;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Favorite), type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PoemId is probably null when you cast e.ClickedItem as TextBlock

Try this

```
Poem poem = e.ClickedItem as Poem;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Favorite), poem);
```

Comment: In my solution, the e.NavigationParameter is not null. However, when the data is passed  to string poem, it is filled as null.

Comment: @Aiseduk Well then you obviously needed to just send a string PoemId or whatever, but the casting I showed you works.